# Command line disabling of Incognito on a Chromebook

Tags: command-line, chromebook, private-browsing

I'm trying to permanently disable incognito mode on a chromebook at the command line level. I'm utilizing a remedy I found here: https://robots.net/tech/how-to-disable-incognito-mode-on-chromebook/

According to the site, if I can add a user to the chronos group, I'll be "effectively removing the ability to use incognito mode." (I'm curious what other effects it may have, but for now I'm most concerned about removing the ability to access incognito mode).

In developer mode I've attempted a couple sudo commands:

```
sudo adduser <user> chronos
sudo usermod -a -G chronos <user>
```

However, I get errors like user does not exist. Cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is the username? The article you've linked pretty clearly states those commands need the username you're working with in the command, as "chronos" is the group you're trying to add a user to. Also, as you EDIT your question to improve it, please take advantage of the formatting tools in the editor to make your commands clearer.

Comment: Thank you for the kind assistance. I’ll try to do better at improving my formatting next time. The username I’d like to use is for one of my kids, so I could use “Larry” for example?

Comment: You have to use the username of the account on the Chromebook that you want to apply that policy to, that is what "<user> means in the context of the instructions you've tried. So, if one of the Chromebook's users is actually "larry" in the system, your command would look like `sudo adduser larry chronos` and so on. Is that what you did?

Comment: Yes, I’m using Larry as the username, but it returns user does not exist. 

Is there a command I can run  while in developer mode to find out what users the system is aware of? And/or, is there a command I can run to successfully create a new user (like Larry) when it tells me Larry doesn’t exist? (When I try to create Larry as a new user, the system returns: Cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later.)

If I can successfully create Larry, then maybe I can add him to the Chronos group.